# Dynamic filtering of posts with custom taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy

I am currently trying to make a business directory where the users can filter the results by:

1. Type of service
2. County

I am using a custom post type for the business directory, and I have created 2 custom taxonomies:

1. Type of service - works like a category
2. County - works like tags

I need a dynamic query that will let my users first choose a type of service, then choose a county and then get a list of results - or the other way around; they choose a county first and then a type of service.

Is this possible? Or do I have to do this with categories and sub-categories?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in your template. Make sure to replace the post_type and custom taxonomies ( service & county ) with their appropriate slugs.

```
    $page_link = get_permalink();
    $services = get_terms( 'service' );
    $counties = get_terms( 'counties' );

    $args = array();
    $args['post_type'] = 'business';
    $args['paged'] = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    if ( isset( $_GET['service'] ) ) {
        $args['service'] = $_GET['service'];
        $page_link = add_query_arg( 'service', $_GET['service'], $page_link );
    }
    if ( isset( $_GET['county'] ) ) {
        $args['county'] = $_GET['county'];
        $page_link = add_query_arg( 'county', $_GET['county'], $page_link );
    }

    if ( is_array( $services ) ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $services as $service ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . htmlentities( add_query_arg( 'service', $service->slug, $page_link ) ) . '">' . $service->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '<li><a href="' . htmlentities( remove_query_arg( 'service', $page_link ) ) . '">None</a></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    if ( is_array( $counties ) ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $counties as $county ){
            echo '<li><a href="' . htmlentities( add_query_arg( 'county', $county->slug, $page_link ) ) . '">' . $county->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '<li><a href="' . htmlentities( remove_query_arg( 'county', $page_link ) ) . '">None</a></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    query_posts( $args );
    if ( have_posts() ){
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            // Do Something
            // Pagination
        } 
    }
```

Comment: thanks Josua, your code with a little changes was my solution.